# Private cocoapod never shows update

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I have a private cocoa pod which I have successfully built and included in my project.

In my project's podfile, I add it as so:

```
pod 'myPrivatePod', git: 'https://git.private.com/myPrivatePod.git'
```

My podspec file is in the root of the project, I followed the example from reachability. When I update my pod, I change version number in xcode as usual, I update the podspec version and source(tag).. I also apply the tab to git. After an update, when I do pod update / pod oudated I never get this new update. I end up having to remove the pod, doing a 'pod install' -> add pod, do 'pod install' again.. At this point I get my latest version.

I feel like I could be missing something, but I've gone through the guides with no luck.

Comment: Fetching a pod from a repository using `:git` will always use the latest commit on `master`: [see the documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod).

Comment: I've been staring at that link for a while... So if I don't specify a tag, it will not use what the podspec tells it to use?

Either way, it still does not get the latest commit. It's simply not fetching any changes unless I remove the pod and re-add it..

Comment: Also - Looking at the Cedar ios example, I have the same setup.. But that one does pick up the updates just fine - using the tag specified in the podspec file for the project...
pod 'Cedar', git: 'https://github.com/pivotal/cedar.git'

https://github.com/pivotal/cedar/wiki/Installation

Comment: What happens if you run `pod install --verbose`?

Comment: Nothing usefull, goes through these steps.. I actually just made a change in my pod, pushed it and did pod install. it didnt' come through.  It doesn't show anything different when it's in the "finding podfile changes"

Comment: Edit - Loos like a pod update now works and updated my podfile.locl... Not sure what I did(if anything)

Answer (score 2):

You never got the update because you should clean the cache of `cocoapods` :

```
pod cache clean --all
```

After that, just call the usual `pod update` and it should work.

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

> pod 'MyLib', :git => 'ssh:path.git', :branch => 'develop' //will fetch last commit of develop branch
>
> pod 'MyLib', :git => 'ssh:path.git', :branch => 'master' //will fetch last commit of master branch
>
> pod 'MyLib', :git => 'ssh:path.git', :commit => '7b1790e' //will fetch a specified commit

You could get more there https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Comment: And it will fetch on update right? - do you see any changes with your lib when running pod outdated?

Comment: yes, have no problem with that. maybe your "git push..." very slow and need some time after?